# Accessing ViewController itself from a class method inside the View Controller in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController in my project that has a class method that uploads a file to a server. It is class method because it will be access by a `NSObject` class that handles the image capturing.

However, as it turns out, I cannot access the ViewController itself from the inside of my static function in the original ViewController. I want to do this in order to show a progress HUD that overlays over the ViewController.

Any idea on how to handle this?

The method is defined as such in the header:

```
+(void)uploadImage:(NSString*)imagePath thumbnailPath:(NSString*)thumbnailPath;
```

Comment: There are a few ways to deal with this. Could you post an example of how to call (or expect to call) this method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple options:

1) Make the method an instance method, and have the NSObject call it on your specific instance of the View Controller.

2) Post a notification in the class method and have your view controller instance subscribe to it.

Comment: Also, You should separate this out into a separate class that handles uploading images. The View Controller should only be worried about UI related things. Doing this would also fix your problem, since you could set an update delegate on the image uploader class which the view controller could set itself to.

Answer (score 1):

You could also abstract this out a bit by [creating a protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) which you can have any object adopt, and pass that in as a dependency;

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(id)someData;
@end

@interface MyObjct
+(void)uploadImage:(NSString*)imagePath thumbnailPath:(NSString*)thumbnailPath dataSource:(id<MyProtocol>)data;
@end
```

This way, it will not matter if its an instance of a `UIViewController` or any other object that implements the methods in `MyProtocol`.